# adding li by dragging from one ul to another ul using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Adding li by dragging from one ul to another ul

e.g.

**First** `ul` list items:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

**Second** `ul` list items: **empty**

When item `a` is dragged and dropped to second `ul` the item have to be added to the second `ul`.

Restrict addition of more than 2 items in second `ul`.

I have used [Sortable Widget](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) (Categories: Interactions) from jquery.ui

But can't implement restriction of adding not more than 2 li items.

Please help me..

DndOptionDiv is first dive have options
 - 1
 - 2
 - 3
 - 4
 i am trying to add options from **sortable1** ul  2 **DndFirstAns** and **DndSecondAns** ul

**css**

```
    .connectedSortable {
        background-color: seagreen;
        width: 150px;
    }
    .DndOptionDivCss {
        width:150px;
        float:left;

    }

    .DndFirstAnsDiv {
        width:150px;
        float:left;

    }

    .DndSecondAnsDiv {
        width:150px;
        float:left;

    }
    ul {
        border:dashed;
        border-width:1px;
    }
```

**aspx code**---

```
 <div d="DndOptionDiv" class="DndOptionDivCss">
            <ul id="sortable1" >
                <li id="1" >1 </li>
                <li id="2" >2</li>
                <li id="3" >3</li>
                <li id="4" >4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="DndFirstAnsDiv" class="DndFirstAnsDiv">
            <ul id="DndFirstAns" >
                <li class="ui-draggable" >1st ans</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="DndSecondAnsDiv" class="DndSecondAnsDiv">
            <ul id="DndSecondAns" >
                <li class="ui-draggable">2nd Ans</li>

        </div>
```

Script for this is

```
$(function () {
        $("#sortable1 li").draggable({
            revert: true,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
            }
        });


        $("#DndFirstAns").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).find("p").html("Dropped!");//$(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Dropped!");
                toDrop = $(ui.draggable);
                //if ($("#queAnsOptions1").find("li[uniqueIdentity=" + toDrop.attr("uniqueIdentity") + "]").length <= 0)//for uniqueId
                //{

                $("#DndFirstAns").append(toDrop);
                //$(ui.draggable).remove();
                //}

            },

        });

        $("#DndSecondAns").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).find("p").html("Dropped!");//$(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Dropped!");
                toDrop = $(ui.draggable);
                //if ($("#queAnsOptions1").find("li[uniqueIdentity=" + toDrop.attr("uniqueIdentity") + "]").length <= 0)//for uniqueId
                //{

                $("#DndSecondAns").append(toDrop);
                //$(ui.draggable).remove();
                //}

            },

        });
        $("#DndFirstAns li").click(function () {
            $(this).appendTo("#sortable1");
        });
        $("#DndSecondAns li").click(function () {
            $(this).appendTo("#sortable1");
        });
    });
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this fiddle might help, from the jquery example you mentioned,

http://jsfiddle.net/T3n4u/

It simply counts how many items are transferred in "receive" event, and when two items are dropped the connectWith property is set, and the first ul.li is not droppable to second ul

```
receive: function(event, ui){
        if(++count > 1)
            $("#sortable1").sortable("option", { connectWith: "" });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you..
now i tried  using droppable and Draggable
i have problem i.e. i want to replace dragged item with dropped item When 2nd ul have max count

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your html and javascript?